# Как написать регулярное выражение для определенного слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть база плохих слов и я хотел бы проверять и все слова и удалять их.

Написал элементарное регулярное выражение, но оно не работает

```
$text="Это FucKinG контент для взрослых"; 
$str=preg_replace("'fuck(.*) 'isU", "", $text);
// результат обработки должен быть таким "Это контент для взрослых"
```

Answer (score 1):

Если на разные слова заменять то можно реализовать так:

```
$trans = array("fuck" => "*ругательство*", "пошел на ***" => "не соизволите удалиться сэр?");
echo strtr("строка с большим количеством ругательств", $trans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ту же задачу можно выполнить проще:

```
$text="Это FucK контент для взрослых"; 
$str= str_ireplace("fuck", "", $text);
print($str);
```

При этом первый аргумент может быть и массивом:

```
$text="Shit Это FucK контент для взрослых"; 
$str= str_ireplace(array("fuck","shit"), "", $text);
print($str);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$text="Это FucK контент для взрослых";
$str=preg_replace("#(fuck)#isU", '', $text);
```

Лишние пробелы можно убрать в конце, после всех зачисток:

```
$str=preg_replace("#(\s{2,})#isU", ' ', $str);
```

Comment: пример не очень удачный привел, немного подправил. я хотел в регулярке указать корень ругательства например одной регуляркой с корнем fuck  можно было отфильтровать такие слова как unFucking

Comment: `\s{2,}` - это -> `{2,}` можно заменить этим -> `+`. Тобишь так `\s+`.